# manage animaton from mesh(GLTF/FBX) with single AnimationClip

Tags: three.js

I am porting our mobile game to webgl and our 3d models in FBX uses a single stream animation and refer to animations by its frame number, example:
0 - 10 Idle
11 - 22 - walk
etc.

in mobile it uses OpenGL ES and our own game engine and animation handler. Looking at Threejs, it seems like most of the things we implemented in our own engine are already handled by it.

How do I do this with threejs, specialy on the part to fade in/out to new animation when it uses a single clip?

most of the animations tutorial for threejs uses multiple clips and i havent found one that uses a single clip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual workflow for solving this issue is to split up the single large clip into multiple instances of `THREE.AnimationClip` by using [AnimationUtils.subclip()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=animat#api/en/animation/AnimationUtils.subclip). This helper function was specifically designed for your use case since you can extract the animations by their respective start and end frames.